Web API JWT token unauthorized error inspite of passing token in authorization header
I created a sample .Net WebAPI core application to understand JWT implementation. The API was created and added JWT based authentication in it. The API returns the token from the token controller. But if we add the token to the header to make subsequent request, the API returns unauthorized error. I'm unable to find where is the issue. I have attached both the client and server code that i have used. Please help to understand what is the issue in the code i have written
API Code
Token Controller
using JWTAuthentication.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;

namespace JWTAuthentication.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TokenController : ControllerBase
    {
        public IConfiguration _configuration;
        public DatabaseContext _context;

        public TokenController(IConfiguration configuration, DatabaseContext context)
        {
               _configuration = configuration;
            _context = context; 
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post(UserInfo userInfo)
        {
            if (userInfo != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInfo.Email) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInfo.Password))
            {
                var user = await _context.UserInfos.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Email == userInfo.Email && u.Password == userInfo.Password);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    var claims = new[] {
                        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, _configuration["Jwt:Subject"]),
                        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()),
                        new Claim("UserId", user.UserId.ToString()),
                        new Claim("DisplayName", user.DisplayName),
                        new Claim("UserName", user.UserName),
                        new Claim("Email", user.Email)
                    };

                    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Jwt:Key"]));
                    var signIn = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
                    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                        _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                        _configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                        claims,
                        expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
                        signingCredentials: signIn);

                    return Ok(new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token));
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest("invalid credentials");
                }
            }
            else 
            {
            return BadRequest();
            }
        }
    }
}


Employee Controller
using JWTAuthentication.Interface;
using JWTAuthentication.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace JWTAuthentication.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/employee")]
    [ApiController]
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IEmployee _IEmployee;

        public EmployeeController(IEmployee IEmployee)
        {
            _IEmployee = IEmployee;
        }

        // GET: api/employee>
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Employee>>> Get()
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(_IEmployee.GetEmployeeDetails());
        }

        // GET api/employee/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Employee>> Get(int id)
        {
            var employees = await Task.FromResult(_IEmployee.GetEmployeeDetails(id));
            if (employees == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return employees;
        }

        // POST api/employee
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Employee>> Post(Employee employee)
        {
            _IEmployee.AddEmployee(employee);
            return await Task.FromResult(employee);
        }

        // PUT api/employee/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Employee>> Put(int id, Employee employee)
        {
            if (id != employee.EmployeeID)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            try
            {
                _IEmployee.UpdateEmployee(employee);
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!EmployeeExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return await Task.FromResult(employee);
        }

        // DELETE api/employee/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Employee>> Delete(int id)
        {
            var employee = _IEmployee.DeleteEmployee(id);
            return await Task.FromResult(employee);
        }

        private bool EmployeeExists(int id)
        {
            return _IEmployee.CheckEmployee(id);
        }
    }
}


Program.cs
using JWTAuthentication.Interface;
using JWTAuthentication.Models;
using JWTAuthentication.Repository;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using System.Text;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(x=>x.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("dbConnection")));
builder.Services.AddTransient<IEmployee,EmployeeRepository>();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer
    (x =>
    { x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        x.SaveToken = true;
        x.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
        { 
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
        };
    }
);
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

//builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Title = "JWTToken_Auth_API",
        Version = "v1"
    });
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
    {
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        Scheme = "Bearer",
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.\r\n\r\nExample: \"Bearer 1safsfsdfdfd\"",
    });
    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                        Id = "Bearer"
                }
            },
            new string[] {}
        }
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();


Calling console App Code
using ConsumeJWTWebApiCore.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace ConsumeJWTWebApiCore.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"https://localhost:44303/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            //var reqMsg=new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, client.BaseAddress+@"api/employee");

            //  var response = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress + @"api/employee");
            JsonContent content = JsonContent.Create(new UserInfo() { Email="admin@abc.com",Password="$admin@2022"});
            var response = await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress + @"api/Token", content);
            string token = null;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            { 
            token = (string?)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            }


           
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var getResp = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress+ @"api/employee");
            if(getResp.IsSuccessStatusCode) 
            {
                var emp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(await getResp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            }
            return View();
        }

     
    }
}



I had a test with your code and I found if I removed new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()), from your claims will make the token worked.

Change your claim iat to new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, ((DateTimeOffset)DateTime.UtcNow).ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString()) can solve your issue per my test. That's because the iat claim represents the time at which the JWT was issued. It should be an integer representing the number of seconds since the Unix epoch (January 1, 1970).

From this document.

The "iat" (issued at) claim identifies the time at which the JWT was
issued.  This claim can be used to determine the age of the JWT.  Its
value MUST be a number containing a NumericDate value.  Use of this
claim is OPTIONAL.


Thanks a lot for your confirmation and I think we can call it a case now : )

Could you inspect the value of the variabale  String token, think it's an object.
May be you need to cast it as object (It's better to create a class Token and cast the serialization as Token) and then get the AccessToken from that Token.
 public class Token
 {
     [JsonProperty("access_token")]
     public string AccessToken{ get; set; }
 }

From:
token = (string?)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

To:
Token token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

then you can use the object Token as the following:
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.AccessToken);


Tried the given suggestion. JsonConvert.DeserializeObject is unable to convert to token object. Its throwing typecasting error.

Try the following on controller:
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]

